# XmlRpc ошибка дублирования методов, можно ли так вообще делать?

Tags: vb.net, rpc

Получаю ошибку

```
-1 Reason: 'Method DTO in type IXCoder has duplicate XmlRpc method name coder.DTO'
```

Идея в том что бы один и тот же метод, вызывать в разных ситуациях с разными количествами аргументов.

На стороне .NET вроде спорных вопросов нету.
В интерфейсе описано две процедуры с разным количеством аргументов.

```
Imports CookComputing.XmlRpc
Imports System

Public Interface IXCoder

    <XmlRpcMethod("coder.DTO")>
    Sub DTO(ByVal jsonTrase As String, ByVal jsonDebug As String)

    <XmlRpcMethod("coder.DTO")>
    Sub DTO(ByVal jsonTrase As String, ByVal jsonDebug As String, ByVal jsonParam As String)

End Interface
```

В реализазации класса описаны методы скажем так

```
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="jsonTrase"></param>
''' <param name="jsonDebug"></param>
Public Sub DTO(jsonTrase As String, jsonDebug As String) Implements IXCoder.DTO

    prepareTraceANDDebud(jsonTrase)

    Model_Coder.model.GenerateDTO(_objTrace)

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="jsonTrase"></param>
''' <param name="jsonDebug"></param>
''' <param name="jsonParam"></param>
Public Sub DTO(jsonTrase As String, jsonDebug As String, jsonParam As String) Implements IXCoder.DTO

    prepareTraceANDDebud(jsonTrase)

    Model_Coder.model.GenerateDTO(_objTrace)

End Sub
```

Visual Studio даже не намекает на ошибки, мол все честно, но при вызове из PHP запроса XMLRPC возникает ошибка, правда не могу понять на чьей стороне она возникает.

P.S. Понятно что можно не заморачиваться и сделать вызовы отдельно, вопрос не в этом, а в истине ).

Comment: На стороне PHP нет перегруженных методов и быть не может, вы неверно поняли вопрос! Со стороны идет вызов через XMLRPC а ему прозрачно, на каком языке его вызывают и на каком языке отдают ответ. И как бы вызов удаленной процедуры, никакого отношения к вызываемому коду отношения не имеет.